# How can i return back the sorted observable which is using async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am having dataSource observable in my table and i am filtering it dynamically depending on the user input in the inputs above the table.

*HTML*

```
<table class="table table-striped border mt-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor="let t of tableHeader">
        <input type="text" [id]="t.key" (keyup)="inputChange($event, t.key)" autocomplete="new-password">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" [appSortObservable]="dataSource$" data-order="desc" data-name="firstname">first name</th>
      <th scope="col" [appSortObservable]="dataSource$" data-order="desc" data-name="lastname">last name</th>
      <th scope="col" [appSortObservable]="dataSource$" data-order="desc" data-name="othernames">other names</th>
      <th scope="col" [appSortObservable]="dataSource$" data-order="desc" data-name="age">age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of  dataSource$ | async">
    <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.othernames }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*TS*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, of } from "rxjs";
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

dataSource = [
    {
      firstname: "James",
      lastname: "Amstrong",
      othernames: "Angel",
      age: 35
    },
    {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Peter",
      othernames: "Ava",
      age: 43
    },
    {
      firstname: "Angie",
      lastname: "Judas",
      othernames: "McAngels",
      age: 45
    },
    {
      firstname: "Abraham",
      lastname: "Isaac",
      othernames: "Juniour",
      age: 20
    },
    {
      firstname: "McAceli",
      lastname: "Elizabeth",
      othernames: "Aaron",
      age: 62
    }
  ];

 
  tableHeader = [
    {
      key: "firstname"
    },
    {
      key: "lastname"
    },
    {
      key: "othernames"
    },
    {
      key: "age"
    }
  ];

  filterKeyValues = this.tableHeader.map(({ key }) => ({ key, value: "" }));

  filterSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.filterKeyValues)

  filter$ = this.filterSubject$.asObservable()

  dataSource$ = combineLatest([
    this.filter$, of(this.dataSource)
  ]).pipe(
    map(([filter, dataSource]) => 
     dataSource.filter(item => 
        filter.every((value) => 
          (new RegExp(String(value.value).toLowerCase())).test(String(item[value.key]).toLowerCase())
        )
      )
    )
  )
  public inputChange(event: any, key) {
    this.filterKeyValues.find(({key: testKey}) => testKey === key).value = event.target.value
    this.filterSubject$.next(this.filterKeyValues)
  }

}
```

I also wanted to sort my table on column click -
so i builded directive for that

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, Renderer2, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Sort } from '../util/sort';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSortObservable]'
})
export class SortObservableDirective {

  @Input() appSortObservable;
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private targetElem: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener("click")
  sortData() {
    console.log('sort observavle', this.appSortObservable);
    return this.appSortObservable
    .pipe(map((data: any) => data.sort(sortByFunc)))
    .subscribe(console.log);
  }
}

const sortByFunc = (a, b) => {
  const nameA = a.age;
  const nameB = b.age;
  return (nameA < nameB) ? -1 : (nameA > nameB) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

the problem here is that i can't find a way to return the sorted observable
in the console.log statement i get the sorted objects after i subscribe but my table - HTML is not updated

Please how can i fix this ?

Comment: You could do so by using the [Output](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-parent-component) event emitter.
Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Yes, how exactly with output emitter in my case, can you write an example please ?

Comment: I writed code for the solution with output emitter, thank you very much man ! But why it is working only with output emitter - why we can't directly modify the stream ?

Comment: You could create an output method like `@Output() dataSortedEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();` and somwhere near you "console.log" you could you could raise the event by `this.dataSortedEvent .emit(sortedData);` - this should do the trick

Comment: OK, you already got it. That's great! input and Output are made for the communication between parent and child component. If you wanted to modify the stream directly from the child component/directive you need to have the the stream outside the parent component, e.g. via a Redux System like [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/)